# Javascript - DOMMouseScroll not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

Was try to enable and disable page scrolling through JavaScript. But seemed bellow method not working on Google Chrome, but working fine on Safari and FireFox -

```
let keys = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40];

function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
    preventDefault(e);
}

export function disableJSScroll() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
        window.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
    document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

export function enableJSScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
        window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/DOMMouseScroll_event

Answer (score 0):

DOMMouseScroll is a non-standard and deprecated event as per MDN docs. Use `wheel` event instead.